# Symfony2 How to authenticate a user with two different user names to access different url

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-2.8, symfony-2.7

I am working on a symfony project and I have a question in the authentication of users that I would like you to solve, since I am new to this.

My project is about a school, where there are teacher type users that have the `username` and `password` attributes in the database. The user name consists of the letter `t` followed by the personal identification number, for example `t48945110`. In addition, teachers have a Boolean attribute to indicate which of them is the school principal (there is only one).

The security settings in my project are as follows:

**Secutiry.yml**

```
security:

  firewalls:

    intranet:
        pattern:  ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: teachers
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
           # use_referer: true
            default_target_path: /teacher
        logout: ~

    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /teacher, roles: ROLE_TEACHER }

    providers:
      teachers:
        entity: { class: School\BackendBundle\Entity\Teacher, property: username}

   encoders:
      School\BackendBundle\Entity\Teacher: { algorithm: sha512 }
```

With the above, the teacher can accerder to his private part through the login form, but the problem I have when I want to access with the director (teacher with the attribute (`director=1`) in the database). I would like this teacher to be able to access with another username, but not save it in the database, just changing the main letter, and then in the authentication look for the normal username of the teacher and check if the director to redirect it to `/ admin` instead of `/teacher`. For example, the head of the school who can access his personal area as a teacher by the user name t48945110 and also can access the administration area of ​​the school with the user name `d48945110`.

This idea is not to create two different login forms, but to access all the users of the application (students, teachers, director ...).

I do not know if it could be done through Events listeners or otherwise. I appreciate your help for help.

Comment: This seems overcomplicated to me. A username should not have any indication on the role(s) the specific user has. Why not have a single admin interface located at admin/ and just restrict the access rights via ACL for the teachers?

Comment: Hello @Atan, thanks for the reply. In this case, to access at admin/ the teacher must access before a private area and add an option to open the administration part from there, right? That was my main idea, but I was unsure if there was any way that the teacher could access each part independently without using two different forms so that he could do so.

Comment: No, what I meant was to use a single login form and just redirect every user (student, teacher, director) to admin/ . Then use ACL rules to limit the access within the admin panel for users depending on their roles. For example a director has two roles: ROLE_TEACHER and ROLE_ADMIN . Teacher only has ROLE_TEACHER.

Comment: That is my idea, but I had designed admin/ and intranet/ independently with different designs, so that only the director can access an admin/ and the rest to intranet/. The same I planted it badly from the beginning.  I think the only option in this case would be to add to the director's content a link that can access admin/ and redirect every user to intranet/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be overcomplicating things. I'm pretty sure your director does not want to login with different usernames to enter the separate sections. Without knowing more details, what I would recommend is changing the `getRoles()` in your `School\BackendBundle\Entity\Teacher` to something like this:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = array('ROLE_TEACHER');
    if ($this->director == 1) {
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_DIRECTOR';
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
    }

    return $roles;
}
```

This is probably the easiest way to have the user be both a teacher having access to their secured area as well as director having access to the admin area without having to switch accounts.

If for some reason this does not work you could have a look at [Security Voters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html). This could look something like this:

```
class TeacherIsDirectorVoter extends Voter
{

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        // This voter will always be used
        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        // This voter will allow access if the currently logged in user is teacher and is a director

        return ($user instanceof Teacher && $user->isDirector());
    }
}
```

Again this will grant access for a teacher who is a director without requiring them to log in as a different user. Be careful with this voter as it will always grant access to all sections of your site to the teacher having `director=1` with the default voter strategy. There are ways to change this or you could add checks based on the provided attributes and the subject being voted on.

I think for your use case the first option (updating the roles) is probably the easiest and will work well for you.

If you want students, teachers and director to be redirected to different pages after login you could do a little trick. In your SecurityController (or wherever you have your loginAction) create a new targetAction() that is used as target after successful login. In your security.yml assign the form_login's default_target_path to that route, instead of /teacher. That action should be accessible by all 3 user groups. Now just redirect, based on whatever roles your user has:

```
public function targetAAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $user->getRoles())) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('intranet_admin_page');
    }
    if (in_array('ROLE_TEACHER', $user->getRoles())) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('intranet_teacher_page');
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('generic_page_for_users');
}
```